# Home page list display a bullets before picture and in multiple column

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I have just started using the new Magento release CE 1.9. I write a code in Home page to display my category product but I observed that the image printed on the page has a bullet mark before each product image and also for 3 column prints it display only two picture and other picture in next new line.

I want to display all the three picture in one line then other 3 in second line and so on.

My website: http://shepcart.com

Comment: Your website is not loading to view the issue https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji2boer9tia9ji3/Screenshot%202014-05-25%2016.22.46.png

Answer (score 2):

You're using list elements that lack appropriate style. Try adding something like:

```
ul.products-grid li.item { list-style-type: none; }
```

to /skin/frontend/red/default/css/styles.css to get rid of those bullets.

Also having two

```
<li class="item last">
```

might not what you had mind mind.